# FileNotFoundException when using fileoutputstream in war to read files in webapp

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

Working on a lift and shift application.

Existing project is in any.

I have a migrated it to a gradle multimodule project that is built into an ear with 2 war files.

Now there is some code in the application that writes to a file placed in the webapp/files/sample.txt

So according to existing code, some data is written to this file then this file is used as an attachment in mail and then the file is cleared again.

This is working fine in any.

Now after migration I am not able to get an handle on the file sample to.txt using the existing code.
It throws file not found exception

They have used facescontext.getCurrentaInstance.getExternalcontext.getRealpath().

Any idea how I can read write to this file.

Comment: So basically I want to write and read to some text file that is present in my webapp directory